# How to save all input data with a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, input, split

Code below saves just last input data. How can I save all entered input data in variables? Assume input data is:

```
2

4 2
1 2 3 4

2 3
1 2
```

code below saves just last two pairs. I need both pairs be saved into `lst`, `N` and `size`.

```
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
  N, size = map(int, input().split(" "))
  lst= [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
```

Comment: A variable can only have one value, so the loop overwrites `size`, `N` and `lst` per iteration. Do you ultimately want a 2d list to store all of the `lst`s? If so, simply append each variable populated within the loop onto another list. If not, please show the desired output structure.

Comment: Yes, I meant a list not a variable

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store multiple values in a single variable unless its a list so incase if you need to store all input values in the same variable just change n and size to lists it will do the job.

Here is the code.

```
T = int(input())
N,size,lst=[],[],[]
for i in range(T):
  temp_list = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
  N.append(temp_list[0])
  size.append(temp_list[1])
  lst.extend( [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")])
```